# Sails.js/Waterline - MySQL Query not returning

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

I am finding some odd behaviour. When I include a certain where clause, the query does not return at all. . .

```js
var query = "SELECT id FROM tbl_jobs WHERE jobSiteId = "+site.id+/*" AND jobStartStamp > "+start_stamp +*/" ORDER BY jobStartStamp ASC LIMIT 1";
//sails.log.error(query);
Visit.query(query,function(err, visit){
  if (err) {
    sails.log.error(err);
    return res.serverError(err);
  } 
  return res.send(visit);
});
//Visit.find({site:site.id, start:{">",start_stamp}).sort({start:"ASC"}).limit.exec
... doesn't work
```

When I comment out the 'jobStartStamp' where clause, the query returns fine. When I put it back in, it doesn't call the callback. I do not get any errors on the sails console.

When I execute the query (with the entire where clause) in phpMyAdmin, I get a response (<1 second).

Any ideas how to find out why this is happening?

Comment: I have noticed if I change the ">" to "<" that it returns with data.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running against the same DB in both instances, or is one DB on your server and another on your desktop? If data returns with "<" rather than ">" it indicates that your server has jobStartStamp at an earlier date/time than start_stamp. 
 Is the Visit callback not being called, or is it getting a null resultset from the query?